# Count values in a list that are represented as values in XML elements.

Tags: xpath

I have some XML like this:

```
<lines>
  <line>
    <entity>H</entity>
    <account>1002</account>
    <taxcode>ESCR04</taxcode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <entity>H</entity>
    <account>1003</account>
    <taxcode>ESCR04</taxcode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <entity>H</entity>
    <account>1004</account>
    <taxcode>ESCR04</taxcode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <entity>H</entity>
    <account>1005</account>
    <taxcode>ESCR0</taxcode>
  </line>
  <line>
    <entity>H</entity>
    <account>1002</account>
    <taxcode>ESCR0</taxcode>
  </line>  
</lines>
```

And a list of tax codes like this:

```
  <Codes>
    <Code>ESCR0</Code>
    <Code>ESCR04</Code>
    <Code>ESCR10</Code>
    <Code>ESCR21</Code>
  </Codes>
```

And I need to determine the number of Code elements in Codes that are represented in 'lines' as a value in lines>line>taxcode. In this example it would be 2.

I understand how to find the number of 'line' elements with one of the listed Codes, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to even approach it the other way around. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are the xml fragments in two separate files/documents?  You probably need to use XQuery then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XPath 2.0 and later you can use `count(/Codes/Code[. = doc('lines.xml')/lines/line/taxcode])`.

Comment: OP can merge both files and use xpath 1.0 with `count(//Codes/Code[. =//lines/line/taxcode])`